# WCF Service receives null request

Tags: wcf

[image]

```
var dataToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mi));

        var req = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Service1.svc/json/MethodName");

        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        req.ContentLength = dataToSend.Length;
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.GetRequestStream().Write(dataToSend, 0, dataToSend.Length);

        var response = req.GetResponse();
```

Here "/json" is my endpoint address and my service is configured with multiple endpoints. As per image here, request i sent is recieving null at server.

If my request format is not proper then suggest proper way to call this service.

// Service inter face

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{


    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method="POST")]
    Response MethodName(Request request);
}
```

// Service1

```
  public class Service1 : IService
  {
      public Response MethodName(Request request)
      {
          some logical operation....
      }
  }
```

// End point configuration (Web config)

```
<endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingJson"
              name="jsonn" contract="Service1.IService" />

<endpoint address="xml" behaviorConfiguration="poxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingXml" name="xmll" contract="Service1.IService" />

<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">          
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
<behavior name="poxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingJson">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingXml">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

// Request class

```
 [DataContract] 
public class Request 
{ 
   string userMobile; 
   string otp; 

   [DataMember] 
   public string UserMobile 
   { 
        get { return userMobile; } 
        set { userMobile = value; } 
   } 
   [DataMember] 
   public string OTP 
   { 
        get { return otp; } 
        set { otp = value; } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Does your service actually take json as input? You never showed the definition.

Comment: Yes, it take json and xml by endpoint configuration. <endpoint address="json" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
                  binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingJson"
                  name="jsonn" contract="Service1.IService" />

Comment: Interface configuration is [WebInvoke(Method="POST")]        
        Response MethodName(Request request);

Comment: Please update your code with *all* information.

Comment: Please check above updated detail.

Comment: Your JSON and XML endpoint configuration looks exactly the same. I'm no JSON expert, but expecting them to act differently might not work.

Comment: Adding service reference it works fine. But some how from rest its not working. May be type of sending is wrong but if it does then how it receive at server?

Comment: Can you suggest me request format to send request? I am adding class detail below,
     [DataContract]
        public class Request
        {
        string userMobile;
        string otp;                
        [DataMember]
        public string UserMobile
        {
            get { return userMobile; }
            set { userMobile = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string OTP
        {
            get { return otp; }
            set { otp = value; }
        }
Note that here more parameters remaining but not enough space to write here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found for this.
I modified endpoint of json behaviour configuration to this,

```
<behavior name="jsonBehavior">          
      <webHttp defaultBodyStyle ="Bare"/>
      <!--<enableWebScript />-->
    </behavior>
```

and removed enableWebScript. Finally my code working.